# Why do my images take 200 MB of RAM when they are ~20KB on disk?

Tags: java, textures, libgdx

I am creating an Android game using libGDX. When I load my nine images it takes 200 MB of RAM. But the images are 10 to 17 KB each. Why the discrepancy? Here is where I create textures from those images:

```
public static HashMap<String, Texture> ground = new HashMap<String, Texture>();
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  ground.put(
  "ground" + i,
    new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("groundImages/ground" + i + ".png"))
  );
}
```

Comment: How compressed are your PNG files? I might be wrong but I was under the impression that loaded textures would be uncompressed.

Comment: png8 , when I dispose textures everything is good with ram but the sprites from that textures shows black squares .

Comment: If you dispose of your textures it's probably not unexpected that you can't use them anymore. Do you know what the uncompressed size of your images are? They may be small files when compressed as PNG, but when uncompressed in memory they probably take up more space.

Comment: how can I get that size?

Comment: If your images are RGBA8888 then the uncompressed size is usually width x height x 4 = size in bytes.

Comment: ok thank you , I computed in that way and each image was 15mb that is really big number 2500x1500 image

Comment: Did you check your ram usage **Before** adding these Images to your game?  To see what RAM is being used by adding these items to your game, you first need a control value to see what RAM your game is using without these images.  Lets say your game is using 170 MB of RAM without 9 images loaded up, then try loading the game with said images and its 200MB.  That means the images take up 30MB of ram vs the 200MB we are assuming here.  Also, you are looping through these images resulting in a decompressed version of however many tiles you are creating in your for loop there.

Comment: I have checked it that was 280mb whole the game and 60mb withoyt them

Comment: Are you generating mipmaps ? If so be sure to consider the memory taken by the complete mipmap chains for 2500x1500 textures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The PNG files are small because they are compressed. When the images are loaded into memory they are uncompressed and therefore take up more space.

Comment: There has to be more to it than that.  17 * 9 = 153.  There's no image compression algorithm I've ever heard of that gives a > 1000:1 compression ratio!

Comment: @MasonWheeler It's certainly possible to have a compression algorithm like that. The OP previously mentioned a 2500x1500 image at 8bpp, and the files were 10-17KB each. If we uncompressed into an 8bpp Texture, the Texture would be ~3.5MB giving us a compression ratio between 1:215 and 1:366. The fact that a 32-bit texture is used is irrelevant in that regard.

Comment: I regularly compress 8TB to <3GB using LZW. It is driven by the data not just the algorithm.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: You can trivially construct an image compression algorithm that can reduce certain four-channel inputs to _four bytes_ (plus, say, another eight bytes for storing the original dimensions), regardless of their original size. These optimal inputs, of course, are single-colour filled images.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: The best way I've found to think about compression is that a compression function maps each element in the space of strings to some other element in the space of strings.  Functions usually map the "redundant-looking" ones to shorter strings (at the cost of making "less-redundant-looking" ones map to longer strings).  There's no reason a particular string with 10 billion characters can't map to a string with a single byte.

Comment: and how can I make 2500x1500 image smaller size on disk without loosing quality?